# Draw radial Gradient on UIView (circle)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, gradient

unfortunately I can't get to a solution with drawing a radial gradient in my UIView.

Look...that's how I want to draw it (this was made in PS):
[image]

But I'm currently stuck on this:
[image]

That's my code:

```
CGGradientRef radialGradient;
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;

size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
const CGFloat *colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(textColor.CGColor);
CGFloat components[8] = { colorComponents[0], colorComponents[1], colorComponents[2], 1.0,  // Start color
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }; // End color

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
radialGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));

CGContextDrawRadialGradient(myContext, radialGradient, midCenter, 8.0, midCenter, 1.0, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);



CGGradientRelease(radialGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
```

I hope someone can give me the right tip ;)

Enjoy the weekend,
Chris

Comment: Have you tried using more than 2 locations ?

Comment: No...let me test it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to use more than 2 locations. With 2 locations you get a constant gradient between the start and end locations. Your sample image shows the start colour for most locations up to the end and a much paler end colour. Looking at the sample image you will need at least 3 locations and to change the end colour.